# Speed up nested for loops in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, dictionary, for-loop

I have a function as below & the inputs are given as:

**Inputs:**

```
items = ['17','2','8','34']
item_mapping = {'17':['17','5','8'],'2':['2','0'],'8':['8','2','90'],'34':['34','33']}
item_history = {'India': {'17': '2021-11-14',
                          '2': '2021-11-10',
                          '8': '2021-11-8',
                          '34': '2021-09-22',
                          '90': '2021-11-5',
                          '33': '2021-11-11',
                          '56': '2021-09-22',
                          '0': '2021-11-3',
                          '5': '2021-11-8']},
                 'USA': {'17': '2021-11-10',
                          '2': '2021-11-20',
                          '8': '2021-11-25',
                          '34': '2021-09-22',
                          '90': '2021-11-6',
                          '33': '2021-11-30',
                          '56': '2021-09-22',
                          '0': '2021-11-1',
                          '5': '2021-11-13']
                 }
```

**The function:**

```
def get_results(items,item_mapping,item_history):
        result_list = [] 
        
        for item in items:

            current_line = [item]
            if item in item_mapping:
                identical_item_list = item_mapping[item]
            else:
                identical_item_list = [item]
            for area, history in item_history.items():
                item_history_list = []
                for identical_item in identical_item_list:
                    if identical_item in items and identical_item in history:
                        item_history_list.append([identical_item, history[identical_item]])
                if len(item_history_list) > 0:
                    sorted_item_history_list = sorted(item_history_list, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
                    selected_item = sorted_item_history_list[0][0]
                    current_line += [area, selected_item]
                else:
                    pass

            master_item_to_item_list.append(" ".join(current_line))

        return result_list
```

For each item in list - 'items', I have the list of items identical to it in the dictionary -'item_mapping'.

I also have a dictionary - 'item_history' which has the dates on which items were sold in different regions.

The objective I am trying to achieve is, for each item, I would like to get the latest sold similar item in each region.

For example, take item 17:
The similar items are ['17','5','8']

```
For region 'India', the latest sold similar item, for item 17 is 17. 

For region 'USA', it is '8'. 

Hence the output line will be : ['17' 'India' '17' 'USA' '8']
```

Similarly, I want to get for all items and write lines to a text file.

When I have hundreds of thousands of items, it takes hours to do this multiple for loops with sorting and searches. How can I optimize this code? Any other data structures I can use?

I tried implementing multiprocessing like below: but it's still equally slow.

```
def get_results(item,item_mapping,item_history):
        result_list = [] 
        current_line = [item]
        if item in item_mapping:
            identical_item_list = item_mapping[item]
        else:
            identical_item_list = [item]
        for area, history in item_history.items():
            item_history_list = []
            for identical_item in identical_item_list:
                if identical_item in items and identical_item in history:
                    item_history_list.append([identical_item, history[identical_item]])
            if len(item_history_list) > 0:
                sorted_item_history_list = sorted(item_history_list, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
                selected_item = sorted_item_history_list[0][0]
                current_line += [area, selected_item]
            else:
                pass

        master_item_to_item_list.append(" ".join(current_line))

        return result_list
```

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import functools
with mp.Pool(28) as pool:
    result = pool.map(functools.partial(get_results,item_mapping=item_mapping,item_history=item_history), items)
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need to sort. You data suggests that for each region -> item, there is only one date stored (which I assume is the latest purchase date for that item in that region). While you loop over the identical keys in a region, just store the one with the greatest date and continue to compare and take max as you check other keys. If on the other hand there are more dates to each item and it isn't shown here, sort the data structure once and then look at the first date of each item only. Also, consider using a DB with proper indices and structure if the data is very large.

Comment: Additionally to the comment of @user1984, dicts are slow (and not very user friendly for this usage). Consider using dataframe-based modules like *Pandas*. Pandas optimise many operations and store data more efficiently than just dicts.

Comment: @user1984 Thanks a lot for the response. You are right. I can avoid the sorting and check max element in the dictionary itself. Your suggestion definitely helps!. Is there anything that I can do in the multiprocessing function to improve speed? I am not very sure if I have implemented multiprocessing the right way. Also, I cannot use any DB for this.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have experience with multi processing in python. Maybe you can rewrite this part of the code and present the multi processing part as a new question, Like how you multi process it or if the multi processing can be improved. Making the question shorter and to the point increases your chances of getting good answers.